# Splunk - I want to add a value from stats count() to a value from a lookup table and show that value in a table

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

The objective of the query im trying to write is to take a count of raw data from the previous month and add that to a count from a lookup table (.csv)

What I have attempted to do is…

```
index=*** source=*** 
| stats count(_raw) as monthCount
| join 
   [ | inputlookup Log_Count_YTD.csv]
| eval countYTD = toNumber(monthCount) + toNumber(TOTAL_COUNT_YTD)
| table countYTD
```

This query doesn’t return any value on a table. The `TOTAL_COUNT_YTD` is the only field from the inputlookup file. Let me know if there is any other information you need to help me out with this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `stats` command transforms the data so it has only 1 field: monthCount.  The `inputlookup` returns only the TOTAL_COUNT_YTD field.  The `join` command works by comparing values of common fields between the main search and the subsearch.  Since there are no common fields no events are joined.

There is no need for `join` in this case.  The `appendcols` command will do, assuming the CSV contains a single field in a single row.

```
index=*** source=*** 
| stats count() as monthCount
| appendcols
   [ | inputlookup Log_Count_YTD.csv]
| eval countYTD = toNumber(monthCount) + toNumber(TOTAL_COUNT_YTD)
| table countYTD
```

FWIW, the `tonumber` function is unnecessary, but doesn't hurt.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I replaced join with appendcols, and that makes sense to me. However, I still get no results. I guess this is because of my stats count() command?

Comment: Change the last line to `| table countYTD monthCount TOTAL_COUNT_YTD`.  If you get results then there's a problem with the `eval`.  Debugging Splunk queries entails running just the base search and adding commands one line at a time until you get an unexpected result.  Fix that line and continue the process until you have it working.

Comment: Figured out my problem. Since I was using a .csv file as my lookup table, the value in the file has commas in it, which Splunk’s toNumber() command doesn’t like. Used regex to solve the problem by removing commas. Thanks again for your help